# Convert string to float SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there any way to convert string to float when reading from the database?
So my column `size` consists of string values (i.e. `"45"`)

How would I get the value as float when I query the db using SQL Alchemy.

I know the easiest way would be to `float(value)` but then if the value is `NULL` I need to deal with catching the exception, etc.
Is there a quick way to do it in SQLAlchemy?

Example:
give me the float value if it exists else return `None`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a column type that does the conversion to and from the database for you.  [See the documentation about `TypeDecorator`.](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_1_0/core/custom_types.html?highlight=typedecorator#augmenting-existing-types)

```
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator

class StringFloat(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String

    def process_literal_param(self, value, dialect):
        return str(float(value)) if value is not None else None

    process_bind_param = process_literal_param

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return float(value) if value is not None else None
```

This assumes the values in the database are either valid floats or `NULL`.  If there are other strings, you could add a `try` block around the `float()` call.

Use this type rather than `String` or `Float` when defining a table or model.

```
class MyModel(Base):
    # ...
    size = Column(StringFloat)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution:

```
myFloat = lambda x: float(x) if x!="NULL" else None
myFloat("45")
myFloat("NULL")
```