# How to get a Python datatype from a SQLAlchemy query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have (sqlite3) database with a `Numeric(10, 2)` field. I want to query for that and work with it as a standard python datatype (for me this is `<class 'float'>`).
In the code below I want a list of floats - nothing more.
How can I do this without manual converting the list?

```
# Python3 pseudocode
class Model(_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Model'
    ...
    _weight = sa.Column('weight', sa.Numeric(10, 2))
    ...

query = session.query(Model._weight)
result = query.all()
print(type(result))
print(type(result[0]))
print(type(result[0][0]))
```

This is the result I can not work with

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

When I use `Numeric(10, 2, asdecimal=False)` and `int` is returned. I know that sqlite can not handle float numbers.

btw. I want to work with that float numbers in matplotlib.

Comment: did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30004254/4954037